# Docker: reload a nodejs app with nodemon

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a *hello, world* express app that I run with `nodemon` so that whenever I change a file the server restarts.

I am packaging the app as a docker image.

**Dockerfile**:

```
FROM node:6.3.0

RUN mkdir -p /opt/app
WORKDIR /opt/app

COPY . /opt/app

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

`npm start` runs `nodemon -L index.js` as defined in [package.json](https://github.com/jatins/node-docker-reload/blob/master/package.json)

However, I can't build the image everytime I make a change to the my app.
I also have a **docker-compose.yml** file, in which I specify the `build` option, but still I can't get the container to reload with

```
version: "2"
services:
  rpro:
    build: .
    command: npm start
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - /opt/app
```

Here the the [entire repo](https://github.com/jatins/node-docker-reload)

---

*How do I achieve server restart on file changes with docker containers? What is the usual dev workflow in such a case?*

Comment: docker-dev is good for this type of things although I dont think it should be run in production

Comment: @meda could you provide a link to docker-dev?

Comment: Sorry i meant node-dev

Answer (score 18):

Ah, the problem seems to be with **docker-compose.yml** `volumes` param.
Changing it to

```
volumes:
  - .:/opt/app
```

makes it work. It tells docker to mount the application folder `.` on the host to the `/opt/app` in the container.

Then after doing `docker-compose up`, the server restarts in case of file changes.

Comment: Inside your dockerfile you wouldn't need to do the RUN mkdir or the COPY commands. Your source and destination are the same here: `COPY . /opt/app`

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if I would call that a problem since it is the usual workflow -- when a file changes that resides in the container, it will trigger a rebuild. If you don't put the file in the container, it won't do that so as @jatin mentions, you can link your Compose directory via `- .:/opt/app` or similar.

If you do this, you don't need to use `COPY . /opt/app` in your build as it will mount over that directory.

Note when you `docker-compose up --build` Docker will not rebuild (restart the server) if the files in the mounted volume change, only if files in the build change. Since it seems you are watching the files via nodemon, it *may* restart (since you are using the legacy watch it should, just note there are cases where it may not recognize the file change).

This is basically fine for development, however in production, clearly you wouldn't want to use `watch` and you most likely would use Docker to monitor and restart the container if it quits (`restart: always`) or use a process manager in non-daemon mode.

Comment: *"Note when you docker-compose up` Docker will not rebuild (restart the server) if the files in the mounted volume change, only if files in the build change."*

Isn't it the other way round? If I remove the `volumes` param from my docker-compose.yml and then do a `docker-compose up`, changes are not picked up, until I explicitly do a `docker-compose build` after every change.

Comment: Yes, if the image is already created, you need to add `--build`. However if you do use `--build` and there are no changes, the image and container should remain untouched.